# C++11 does not generates special functions / default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

Following my previous question, I found a problem with `C++11` too, considering

```
typedef struct
{
    int f_1;
    float f_2;
} *Tptr;
```

this definition of a pointer to an anonymous struct named `Tptr`, doesn't generates a valid `default constructor` for the `struct` that `Tptr` it's supposed to point to.

This can be verified using the following code

```
#include <iostream>
typedef struct
{
    int f_1;
    float f_2;
} *Tptr;
int main()
{
    ...
    Tptr k = NULL;
    // trying to initialize a with a copy
    decltype(*k) a = decltype (*k)();
    // or with an ambiguos call
    decltype(*k) a(decltype (*k)());
    ...
}
```

Conceptually the `decltype(*k)` works, thanks to the fact that `k` is `statically declared` ( and the resulting type is something like a reference to T, `T&`, not really a plain `T` ) .

As I understand what is going on the real problem is that there is no constructor for the pointed `struct` and I'm wondering why the compiler doesn't create the default special functions for this `struct` . The compiler has all the information that it needs to build an object that will replicate the required structure in such a way that an instance of `Tptr` will be able to point to a valid object, so why the compiler doesn't do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem has nothing to do with the lack of a constructor.

> ```
> decltype(*k) a = decltype (*k)();
> ```

This is invalid because `decltype (*k)` is a reference to your anonymous struct, *not* your anonymous struct. If you want to get your anonymous struct, you can use `std::remove_reference<...>::type`:

```
std::remove_reference<decltype(*k)>::type a = std::remove_reference<decltype(*k)>::type();
```

> ```
> decltype(*k) a(decltype (*k)());
> ```

This is valid but does not do what you want. This declares `a` as a function, returning `decltype(*k)`, and taking `decltype (*k)()` as its parameter. You would need extra parentheses to let it be interpreted the way you want:

```
decltype(*k) a((decltype (*k)()));
```

but now you get the same problem as with your first attempt, and you could solve it the same way.

(Of course, in real code, I hope you simply give your `struct` a name.)

Comment: thanks, I was wrong about the first form of initialization but regarding my second example I was intentionally writing something to show that it would be ambiguos from a compiler standpoint ( as you pointed out, it's interpreted as a function ). I also was doing some research hoping to find something in the standard library to "remove that reference", strangely enough I didn't think about that simple signature / name. Thanks again.

Comment: Also I'm assuming that I can't find a way to do this without declaring `k` first ?

Comment: @user2485710 You could use `std::remove_pointer<Tptr>::type`.

Comment: thanks, to be fair I also tried `Tptr k = new std::remove_reference<decltype(*k)>::type;` and it works too. Thanks again